# Creating website.com/newPage in reactjs App when website.com us running react App

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a website running a react app such as website.com
I want to have the user routed to a link on my react app such as website.com/newPage 
Here is my Router. If I type in website.com/newPage into the browser, it does not go to the newPage.

```
    <main className="App">
      <Router basename="website">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<mainPage />} />
          <Route path="/newPage" exact element={<newPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </main>
```

Any suggestions on what to do? I looked around online but I have no idea what it is called that I am trying to do so I have had no luck.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing The gist: redirect the page requests for the sub-routes your app handles to the root index.html file so the React app loads and can handle the internal routing/navigation to the correct page that was requested.

Answer (score 0):

When `basename` is set, the path will be prefixed with the `basename`. `<mainPage/>` will be displayed in `website.com/website` and `<newPage/>` will be displayed in `website.com/website/newPage`

This should be the code for desired results (react router v6)

```js
<main className="App">
      <Router >
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<mainPage />} />
          <Route path="newPage" element={<newPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </main>
```

Comment: This still gives me a 404 not found

Comment: I should also mention this is deployed with apache and website.com does work, but website.com/newPage does not